# Change text button action of picker

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, picker

My question is simple but I do not know if it is possible to do

how i change text button (Done)?

**My picture of Picker**

[image: My picture of Picker]

it is for Xamarin Forms.

Comment: This is IOS specific, so I'd suggest making a custom renderer for your picker and messing around with the pickerrenderer.Control properties. I don't know if this is possible because the thing that pops up when you click the picker might be private and inaccessible to you.

Answer (score 1):

Is doable but there is not an easy way to do it. If you check [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/PickerRenderer.cs#L37) the done button is private in the PickerRenderer as well as the Toolbar object containing it which means none of them are exposed from outside the renderer.

You could however take this renderer as base and create a custom renderer where you can expose a property for the "Done" button text.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with Xamarin, but you can use UIAppearance to style some of the UIBarButtonItems you don't have direct access to (such as a picker displayed from an embedded web view). Just do something like so at launch:

```
let appearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
appearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
```